# how to run a python script on teamcity 10

Tags: python-3.x, teamcity-10

I have teamcity 10. can you please tell me how to run a python script (.py) in teamcity . is it necessary to have a plugin ? or is there any other way via command line etc?

Comment: can anyone  suggest a suitable method for same

Answer (score 0):

There's a python plugin, developed by a member of the TeamCity team: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9042-python-runner

Alternatively, you can always use a command line task to invoke a python executable directly

```
<path to python exe> <path to script>.py
```